# Solving Fokker Planck Equation for steady state solution using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve the FPE (Equation (4) in paper) for the steady state solution to reproduce Fig 2(b)&(c) in mathematica using ND Solve. The functions and parameter values I used are as described in the methods section of the paper

[https://home.gwu.edu/~glan/files/2012.Nature.Physics%20-%20The%20energy%A8Cspeed%A8Caccuracy%20trade-off%20in%20sensory%20adaptation.All.pdf](https://home.gwu.edu/%7Eglan/files/2012.Nature.Physics%20-%20The%20energy%A8Cspeed%A8Caccuracy%20trade-off%20in%20sensory%20adaptation.All.pdf)

The set of equations are:

$ 0 = -\partial_mJ_m(a,m)- \partial_aJ_a(a,m)   $

$ J_m(a,m) = F_mP(a,m) - \Delta_m\partial_mP(a,m) $
$  J_a(a,m) = F_aP(a,m) - \Delta_a\partial_aP(a,m) $

$ F_a(a,m) = -\omega_a[a-G(s,m)]; F_m(a,m) = -\omega_a(a-a_0)C\partial_mG(m)$

$ G(m)= 1/[1+e^{-2m}] $

$\omega_m, \omega_a, \Delta_m, \Delta_a, C$ are all constants. I chose $\beta = 0$ and s = 1.

The problem has no flux boundary conditions:

$J_m(a,m=0)=J_m(a,m=4)=J_a(a=0,m)=J_a(a=1,m)=0.$

However, the only solution I get is zero.

This is my code:

```
Subscript[K, 0] = 1;
Subscript[K, d][m_] = Subscript[K, 0] E^(2 m);
H = 1;
s = 10;
G[m_] = 1/(1 + (s/Subscript[K, d][m])^H)
Subscript[\[Omega], m] = 5;
Subscript[\[Omega], a] = 50;
Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], m] =  0.01*5;
Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], a] = 0.01*50;
Subscript[F, m][a_, m_] = -Subscript[\[Omega], a]*(a - G[m]);
Subscript[a, 0] = 0.5;
Subscript[C, 1] = (
  Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], m] Subscript[\[Omega], a])/(
  Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], a] Subscript[\[Omega], m]);
\[Beta] = 0;
Subscript[F, a][a_, m_] = 
  Subscript[\[Omega], 
   m]*(a - Subscript[a, 
     0])*(\[Beta] + (1 - \[Beta])*Subscript[C, 1]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(m\)]\(G[m]\)\));
Subscript[J, m][a, m] = 
  Subscript[F, m][a, m] P[a, m] - Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], m] \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(m\)]\(P[a, m]\)\);
Subscript[J, a][a, m] = 
  Subscript[F, a][a, m] P[a, m] - Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], a] \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(a\)]\(P[a, m]\)\);
eqn = -\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(m\)]\(
\(\*SubscriptBox[\(J\), \(m\)]\)[a, m]\)\) - \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(a\)]\(
\(\*SubscriptBox[\(J\), \(a\)]\)[a, m]\)\);
ufun = NDSolve[{eqn ==  
    NeumannValue[
      Subscript[F, m][a, 0]/Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], m] P[a, m], 
      m == 0] + 
     NeumannValue[
      Subscript[F, m][a, 4]/Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], m] P[a, m], 
      m == 4] + 
     NeumannValue[
      Subscript[F, a][0, m]/Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], a] P[a, m], 
      a == 0] + 
     NeumannValue[
      Subscript[F, a][1, m]/Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], a] P[a, m], 
      a == 1]}, P, {a, 0, 1}, {m, 0, 4}]
```

Can anyone please help and let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `P = 0` certainly is a valid solution.  If there are others, you might try the `InitialSeeding` option to see whether doing so gives you other solutions.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I tried that but I still get the same solution. Alternatively, I tried solving the complete FPE (with the time derivative, and making P = P[a,m,t]) where t goes from 0 to some large value. But in that case the solution explodes. Thanks.

Comment: I did notice that the arguments of `NeumannValue` are very large, for instance, `NeumannValue[(100000 E^(-2 m) P[a, m])/(1 + 10 E^(-2 m))^2, a == 1]`.  Are you sure that this is correct?

Comment: It is not supposed to be this large, the [Delta]_a had to be multiplied by 2*omega_a and [Delta]_m by 2*omega_a , this makes [Delta]_a= 5 and [Delta]_m = 0.5. This reduces this 100000 to smaller values. I had this correct in my non-stationary implementation but it still blows up. However, it does take longer to blow up if I reduce that factor by adding more scaling terms.
Also my solution takes negative values, which should not happen since its a probability distribution and must be normalized (which also isnt happening here.)